# How to write test cases to check high availability of web service

Tags: web-services, testing, service, high-availability

i have two servers server1 and server2 with a load balancer to maintain the High availability. now i have to deploy a web service on server1 and server2 and should have only one url to access the web-service from both the servers.Now i have to write few tests to check the HA of servers example:
 1. if i switch off or take out the server1 it should not stop rather it should get response from server2 and in test script i have to show it is getting response from server2.

any help !!!

Answer (score 0):

There are probably fancier ways to do this but I simply modified the content on each server a little.  I add a hidden string on the web page to indicate which server the content is returned from.

The test script can check this value and do a count to see how many times it is served from each.  If you are doing manual testing you can simply view the source of the web page (if HTML is what you are looking at) and check the value.  This is helpful to see if you are getting a true balanced system as well as seeing if it works when one server drops off.

This probably won't be an issue, but there are some load balancing systems that *glue* a user to a particular server so after the first response all additional responses will come from the same place.  To handle this you need to make sure requests appear independent to the system handling the balancing.  This typically means a clean session but it could depend on other variables (possibly IP address) as well.